# List index out of range when the index exists

Tags: python, list, cross-validation

I'm new to Python so this may have a very simple solution but I'm trying to implement the kFold Cross Validation algorithm.

To do this I split the test data into bins which I will then assign to test/train and test on for accuracy.

```
bins = np.array_split(indices, foldK)
```

Result of `len(bins)` is 5 and I can't imagine why the indexes would be something other than 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 but when I do:

```
for i in range(0,foldK):
    foldTrain=[] # list to save current indices for training
    foldTest=[]  # list to save current indices for testing
    print(i)
    foldTest = bins[i] #current index to test
    foldTrain = bins #rest of indexes to train
    foldTrain.pop(i)
```

I get an error "list index out of range" at `foldTest = bins[i]` on the 4th iteration, index 3.

Comment: How about adding `print(bins)` before `print(i)`?

Comment: See the duplicated question. `foldTrain = bins` doesn't do exactly what you think it does

Comment: Ohh.. Why did it get smaller ??

Comment: See my comment **and** the linked questions